# Bootstrap grid won't rescale for phone but rescales when i enter a width manually

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

I was working on an html page. When i load it on my phone it wasn't scaled properly. Which is odd because i used the F12 tool in my browser and it worked fine.

I checked back at the F12 debug tool and found something interesting. When i select a phone. Scaling won't work anymore.
[No scaling when phone is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH5LQ.png)

On the other hand. When I edit the width manually, scaling works.
[Scaling works if i enter width manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIshD.png)`

Here is the page. I don't know whats going on. It's 2am please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Schnelltest</title>

</head>
<body class="bg-light">
<div class="container">

    <!--/* Workaround for bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738 -->
    <!--@thymesVar id="post" type="your.package.Post"-->
    <!--@thymesVar id="title" type="String"-->
    <!--@thymesVar id="content" type="String"-->
    <!--*/-->
    <div class="py-5 text-center">
        <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="../static/placeholder.png" alt="" width="72" height="57">
        <h2>Schnelltestzentrum Hochzeitsgeschäft</h2>
        <p class="lead">Um Wartezeiten zu verkürzen haben Sie die Möglichkeit Ihre Daten bereits im Vorfeld
            festzuhalten. Nach Zustellung Ihres Testergebnisses werden Ihre persönlichen Daten von unseren Servern
            gelöscht.</p>
    </div>
    <h4 class="mb-3">
        Anmeldung Covid-19 Schnelltest
    </h4>

    <form th:action="@{/registerUser}" th:object="${registrationDto}" method="POST">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Vorname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:field="*{firstName}" aria-describedby="nameHelp"
                       required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3">
                <label for="surname" class="form-label">Nachname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" th:field="*{surName}"
                       aria-describedby="surnameHelp" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="input-group has-validation">
                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="*{eMail}" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Die E-Mail wird benötigt um Ihnen ihr Ergebnis zu senden.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="birthday" class="form-label">Geburtsdatum</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birthday" th:field="*{birthDate}"
                   aria-describedby="birthdayHelp" required>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">

        <h4 class="mb-3">Adresse</h4>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="street" class="form-label">Straße</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" th:field="*{street}"
                           aria-describedby="streetHelp" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="housenumber" class="form-label">Hausnummer</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="housenumber" th:field="*{houseNumber}"
                           aria-describedby="housenumberHelp" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="zipCode" class="form-label">Postleitzahl</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="zipCode" th:field="*{zipCode}"
                           aria-describedby="zipCodeHelp" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="place" class="form-label">Ort</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place" th:field="*{place}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">
                <p>Ich habe die <a th:href="@{/dsgvo}">Datenschutzerklärung</a> zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben und Daten zur Beantwortung meiner Anfrage vorübergehend elektronisch erhoben und gespeichert werden.</p></label>
        </div>


        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Bestätigen</button>

    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out reading documentation can prove to be helpful.
I added
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
It works with f12 tool. I'm gonna redeploy and check rendering on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out reading documentation can prove to be helpful. I added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

works fine now